# Passing runtime parameter to constructor in Hilt

Tags: java, android, dagger-hilt

In Dagger, we can pass the runtime parameter through component.builder.  But how to achieve that in hilt where the Component is Built in?

```
public class ProgressData {
private int percent;
@Inject
public ProgressData(int percent) {
    this.percent = percent;
}
public int getPercent() {
    return percent;
}
public void setPercent(int percent) {
    this.percent = percent;
}
```

How to inject an object of ProgressData in the main activity while percent data is set in runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.
First Annotate the constructor with **@AssistedInject**. then we have to annotate percent as **@Assisted**.

```
public class ProgressData {
    private int percent;
    @AssistedInject
    public ProgressData(@Assisted int percent) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    
    public int getPercent() {
        return percent;
    }

    public void setPercent(int percent) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }
}
```

Then to provide value for percent we have to create a factory interface where we can pass all dependent variables. we have to annotate it with **@AssistedFactory**. Hilt will implement it internally.

```
@AssistedFactory
public interface ProgressDataFactory{
    ProgressData create(int percent);
}
```

Then from Activity or where we want we have to Inject the **ProgressDataFactory** .then we can call create function.

```
@Inject ProgressDataFactory progressDataFactory;
progressData=progressDataFactory.create(10);
```